# How can I add this assembly and use its functions in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to use the [Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider) DLL in Powershell. In particular, I want to instantiate its class and call that class's Encrypt() and Decrypt() methods in Powershell, so I can write functions that encrypt and decrypt Web.config connection strings.

If I examine the DLL in dotPeek, I see it defines one namespace `PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider`, and one class within that namespace with the same name.

I expected to be able to add the type and then instantiate the class, based on things I've read about *other* assemblies on the web. [This page on using WinSCP with Powershell](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#example) is just example.

I can add the type with no problems.

```ps
PS> $asmPath = "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.1.0.1\lib\NET40\PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.dll"
PS> Add-Type -Path $asmPath
```

However, I can't create an object

```ps
PS> new-object PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider
new-object : Cannot find type [PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

I can see that it does actually get loaded with

```ps
PS> $asm = [appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |? { $_.Location -eq $asmPath }
PS> $asm

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.1.0.1\lib\NET40\PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.dll

PS> $asm.FullName
PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=34da007ac91f901d
```

And, if I add the type with `-PassThru`, I can see that it does have the member functions I want in it somewhere (member list trimmed down for length):

```ps
PS> $type = Add-Type -Path $asmPath -PassThru
PS> $type.GetMembers() | Select-Object name,membertype,declaringtype,module

Name         MemberType   DeclaringType                                                               Module
----         ----------   -------------                                                               ------
...
Initialize       Method   Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider   PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.dll
Decrypt          Method   Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider   PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.dll
Encrypt          Method   Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider   PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.dll
...
```

How can I call these member functions?

Why can I not call them the way I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reflection I see that the `Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider` class is marked `internal` and has no explicit constructors.  I was able to instantiate it by calling the [`Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6ycw1y17) on the only (empty) [`constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo):

```
$type = Add-Type -Path 'PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.dll' -PassThru;
$emptyConstructor = $type.DeclaredConstructors[0];
$provider = $emptyConstructor.Invoke($null);
```